# How do I get bubble-like functionality with matter.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, matter.js

I'm trying to get the circles to move around randomly like bubbles.

I've turned off gravity and added a force but it eventually zeroes out. How do I get the matter bodies to continuously move?

Thanks!

```
function addCircle(world) {
    var circle = Bodies.circle(getRandom(X), getRandom(Y), 30, {
      restitution: 0.5,
      force: { x: Common.random(-0.1, 0.1), y: Common.random(-0.1, 0.1) },
    });
    World.add(world, circle);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your optoins add `frictionAir:0` and `restitution:1`

I think this should do it but they still might loose energy somewhere else. If so you can look at https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Body.html#properties